# Remove paragraph spacing before very large text

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, line-spacing

Using Word, I'm creating very large labels with text that is set to a font size of 300.

I have the paragraph spacing before and after set to zero, but Word insists that there be approximately two inches of space before and after the text.

How do I get rid of that leading and following space?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you may be describing are the page margins.

From the top ribbon -

1. Select Layout > Margins.
2. Select the preset margin measurements you want or
   Select Custom Margins and enter the values you want.
   If you want to always use these margins, then click "Set As Default" prior to clicking 'Ok'

An alternative way of doing this is using the Ruler:
From the top ribbon,

1. Select View > and check Ruler
2. Press Ctrl-A to select the entire document
3. User your mouse to hover over the horizontal ruler at the top of the page until the arrow cursor becomes a double arrow (you'll see a tooltip that says, "Left Margin" or "Right Margin")
4. Slide the double arrow cursor to the left or right to adjust the margin.
5. To adjust the top or bottom margins, hover your cursor over the inner border of the gray area of the vertical ruler until your cursor becomes a double arrow. Then, slide the double-arrow cursor up or down to adjust the margin.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems that you have selected a style, such as shown below.

[image: MS Word Styles]

A style setting include not only the name and size of a font, but also **the spacing above and below the line**. You can change that style by editing [the MS Word template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/using-word-templates-dynamics-365) you are using, reducing spacing both above and below the text. All documents created in the future will have line spacing as set in the template.

You can also [reduce line spacing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-line-spacing-in-word-04ada056-b8ef-4b84-87dd-5d7c28a85712) in just the current document:

- Open the menu item  *Design | Paragraph Spacing*.
- Decrease the numbers in *Before* and *After*. They can even be *negative* to decrease spacing yet more.
- Check *Don't add space between paragraphs*.
- Set *Line spacing* to *Single*.

[image: Set line spacing]

Answer (score 0):

I wanted you to be aware of something not previously mentioned in the two excellent answers already provided.

Do you ever experiment with the "Font" features on the "Advanced" tab?  That tab offers a number of different options to include options related to spacing.  The following image shows what it offers:

[image: font options]

Again, if none of the other answers have helped, I highly recommend you see what these options can do for you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: First of all, thank you for the feedback.  I suppose that I may have incorrectly assumed that some of those features on the Advanced tab could help manipulate the vertical space between letters.  If this is correct — kerning only applies to the horizontal space between letters — what about the other features on that tab?  Are they capable of adjusting space vertically between letters?  If not, let me know and I'll just delete this "answer" altogether.